# WP Как удалить панель создания меток для ролей

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, что необходимо прописать в `functions.php`, чтобы пользователи, которые не имеют роли администратор, не могли редактировать метки (`tags`)? Для них элемент отображаться не должен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел вот [такой ответ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49741/is-it-possible-to-disable-certain-user-roles-from-creating-tags?newreg=a497bbfaf6df489faa0af35f6b5fd76e), но это немного не то, поскольку мне полностью необходимо скрыть данную таксономию, не через `css`

Comment: Там же в ответе есть ссылка на решение  в другом вопросе.

Comment: и в том ответе рекомендуют, приделать `css` который будет скрывать блок. Это немного не то, что мне необходимо.(Костыли которые обходятся если есть доступ к Панели разработчика) Хотелось бы решение через отключение хука.

Comment: Ты же просил скрыть, а не удалить. Вот с пом css и скрывают. (а шибко умным авторам, которые могут навредить сайту можно по голове бить :) ) ЗЫ. Сомневаюсь что можно удалить только поле меток, но точно можно перед постингом очищать данные для этих ролей.

Comment: критика принимается, вопрос поправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения поставленной задачи в `functions.php` необходимо добавить php код.

```
add_action( 'init', 'prefix_unregister_tags', 99 );

function prefix_unregister_tags() {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'post' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете скрыть панель создания ярлыков для пользователей без прав администратора, добавив следующий код в файл functions.php вашей темы WordPress:

```
function hide_taxonomy_metabox() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag', 'post', 'side' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hide_taxonomy_metabox' );
```

Этот код проверяет, не имеет ли текущий пользователь возможности «manage_options» (что эквивалентно роли администратора), и если да, то он удаляет мета-поле «tagsdiv-post_tag», которое представляет собой панель для создания тегов.

Comment: Я проверил ваш скрипт, на роли - Автор, и данный таб продолжает отображаться для него.

Comment: К сожалению, в таком случае, я не знаю проблему